# Hiding list item while selected

Tags: c#, html, drop-down-menu

I'm new to c# programming and still learning. Right now I am trying to make a gadget that lets me change a webpage phone status to not ready. basically what I got is listed below.

```
    private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        webBrowser1.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
        switch (comboBox1.Text)
        {
            case "Documentation":
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link-NOT_READY5").InvokeMember("click");
                comboBox1.Items.Remove("Documentation");
                break;
            case "Innovation Hours":
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link-NOT_READY4").InvokeMember("click"); break;
            case "Lunch":
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link-NOT_READY1").InvokeMember("click"); break;
            case "Meeting":
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link-NOT_READY3").InvokeMember("click"); break;
            case "Restroom/Break":
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link-NOT_READY2").InvokeMember("click"); break;
            case "Training":
                webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("link-NOT_READY6").InvokeMember("click"); break;


            case "Cancel":
                break;
        }
    }
```

So the idea is that while I have documentation for example selected it will be hidden from a drop down box. When i go in to Innovation hours, Innovation Hours is removed from the list and then Documentation is inserted back in to the list.

On the webpage side, when I select Documentation it removes the link so the second time that I click on the link inside the app it crashes because the "Documentation" link is no longer there. When I go back in to Innovation Hours, the Documentation link comes back but Innovation Hours is now hidden.

I tried removing documentation and then hoping to see it go back in to the list when it is not selected but once I remove it, documentation does not go back in to the list.

I feel like it is something simple but im not thinking clearly here. Any ideas in which directions to head with this would be great!

Thanks guys!